# How come NTFS is still a trade secret if there's an open source implementation of it?

Tags: ntfs

As I understand it, Tuxera has [a community version](http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-download/) of its ntfs-3g NTFS driver for *nix which has full source for download. How come MS still regards NTFS as a trade secret?

Comment: That's not really an SO-oriented question, though it's straight-forward enough. If I had a secret way of making apple sauce, and you found a way of making apple sauce that tasted like mine, and told everyone about it, that wouldn't mean I didn't have a secret. In fact, now I have two secrets; the original recipe and the answer to the question "is your recipe the same as the one Alexander told everyone?".
Whether I was doing myself any favours keeping the secret is another matter (maybe I still think my sauce is better in some way). Note I can't accuse you of copying my sauce, since it's secret

Comment: Thanks. That makes some twisted kind of sense, i guess.